# How to prevent QGIS automatically moves panel positions after the program restarts

Tags: qgis, windows-10, user-interface, panel

I want to keep the user interface consistent. But each time I launch QGIS, the panel positions moves a little bit. 
Below are three screenshots showing the first, second, and third time I launch QGIS. The panel positions moves downwards a little bit each time. 
How can I fix it? I'm using QGIS 3.10 on windows 10 Home eidtion version 1809. 
[image: first time]
[image: second time]
[image: third time]